# PHP copy function is slow

Tags: php, copy

I want transfer file from another server to my server

But this code very slow ( 10MB file = more than 15 second )

```
$link = "http://demo.com/file.mp3";
copy($link,'file/'.urldecode(basename($link)));
```

How best solution for this ?

Comment: Check which server is the slowest and replace it? Buy a faster internet connection? Really, anything is possible, but `copy()` is the easiest, and probably fast enough, way to do this.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this code launch by cron jobs and internet connection not  use. how can i check server speed ?

Comment: Sorry, well, whatever connection there is between your two servers, it could be slow. To check the server speed you first look at the hardware. Is it a fast expensive machine or a cheap slow one? That will tell you most you need to know. Then you can run disk speed tests on them, because copying mainly depends on disk speed.